# Scipy fmin with integer solution

Tags: python, integer, scipy, minimize, simplex

I need to minimize a function that only allows integer input. Can I solve it with [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.8.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html)? Otherwise, is there any alternative?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry @SwimBikeRun it has been more than 7 years and I don't remember it :(

Comment: Have some comments here that helped me. In my case, it was monotonically decreasing (no local minima), so a simple bracketing bisect worked fine and although it's not as fast as a potential solution from root finding analogs (would be interested if possible for the math theory aspect), it's still very very fast as the problem of finding a root at maximum precision isn't an issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959501/how-to-minimize-a-real-function-with-only-integer-input?noredirect=1#comment111338050_62959501