# How to minimize a real function with only integer input

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Which optimization algorithms work for integer input, float output?

One thought is just using Brent search but making up a method that interpolates two nearest points to fake a real number input as opposed to an integer input.

My second thought is that seems like such a common need, there must already be something in scipy to do it and/or an algorithm more suited for it?

Bisect certainly works for this, but for huge inputs, its convergence time could be improved. Something hybrid like Brent optimization would be better.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Example

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i-5+.8)

# a = [-4.2, -3.2, -2.2, -1.2, -0.19999999999999996, 0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 3.8, 4.8]
# How to find a[x] such that a is as close to 0 as possible? x = 4, a = -0.2
```

Comment: Not too familiar with Brent's method other than wikipedia, but root finding methods such as that seem like overkill when you have discrete inputs (like your example).  Bisection with a trillion values is guaranteed to converge in less than 33 steps @ O(log N), which is pretty quick.

Comment: Excellent point! That's it right there. And now I understand why it's not in the std lib. After testing some various examples using my function I made up to turn it into a real valued problem, I was numerically coming to the solution with timeit that bisect was faster too.

Comment: More generally, optimization problems with variables restricted to integer values fall under the heading of "integer programming", a subfield of constrained optimization. There is lots of fun to be had there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root finding with something better than bisection doesn't make sense for integer search space as it's already very very fast. A trillion values converges in less than 33 steps for example.

(See comment from AirSquid above)